# $_POST empty after form submit

Tags: php, forms, post

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://mywebsite.com/adir">
    Yes 
    <input type="radio" name="do" value="truedeletelist" CHECKED />
    <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="listname" />
    No
    <input type="radio" name="do" value="backtoapp" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Why is it that when I submit this form the variable $_POST['do'] and $_POST['listname'] are empty?

EDIT:

here is a complete version, and it still does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?

if(!isset($_POST['do'])) {
  echo $_POST['listname'];
  echo $_POST['do'];
}
elseif($_POST['do'] == "deletelist") {

    echo "Are you sure you want to delete the list?";

    ?>
      <form method="POST" action="http://mywebsite.com/app/test.php">
        Yes 
        <input type="radio" name="do" value="truedeletelist" CHECKED />
        <input type="hidden" name="listname" value="list name" />
        No
        <input type="radio" name="do" value="backtoapp" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    <?

}



?>

</body>
</html>
```

I am running PHP 5.4

Comment: where is the `input` with name `listname` in your code ?

Comment: Because **1)** You're `echo`ing a `$_POST` field at a `hidden` `input` `value`. Why? Who is passing that post to your post form? Where does it come from? And **2)** even if that would produce any results, `$_POST[listname]` is wrong syntax, since `listname` should be quoted.

Comment: And there is no way to answer your question since your snippet is completely out of scope and it lacks more information about your context, before and after codings and etc. Please remake your question if you're expecting some answer.

Comment: After you submit this form, `$_POST` will always contain "backtoapp" value(since you seem to be hardcoding it) in the action url. You seem to access `$_POST[listname]`(which is not a syntax error) from another page. You have to send it as a hidden element for the action page to get it.

Comment: Your code is running. I copied your code and print. Its give me do = "truedeletelist "

Comment: @AedixRhinedale What you said doesn't help because it doesn't matter where that info comes from, it prints out fine in the outputted HTML. The problem here is on the form submit. Also you are wrong, my syntax is perfectly fine.

Comment: Yes, @PareshGami I tested the snippet and it works fine, it's something to do with how PHP is processing the form. All of my other forms are raw php run through WordPress posts, but this code is outside of WordPress and does not retain POST values.

Comment: but, $_POST['do'] == "deletelist"; //Here, it should be "truedeletelist".


elseif($_POST['do'] == "truedeletelist") {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It is a problem with htaccess rules written by Wordpress on the root directory. When I switched the form action to point to index.php instead of just the directory, it worked like a charm.

i.e.

```
  <form action="http://mywebsite.com/app/index.php" method="post">
```

was the change I made that fixed it.